# How to validate URL RegularExpressionValidator NOT a CASE Sensitive

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have tried like this

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
    ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
    runat="Server"
    ControlToValidate="txtWebUrl"
    class="red"
    ValidationExpression="/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi"
    ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid URL"
    Display="Dynamic"
/>
```

Comment: `&//=` typo in the regex?

Comment: you need to escape the forward slashes..

Comment: can u give me sample codes???

Comment: /((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/

Comment: @Kaushik Maheta its not taking like this HTTPS://www.google.co.in

Comment: use scripts otherwise..